# Python - Comparing 2 identical strings returns 'False'

Tags: python, string, compare, equals

When I compare these 2 strings, the value I get is `False`.

```
a = "comentar"
b = "️comentar"
print(a == b) # False
```

How could I fix this? I have tried changing the encoding of both strings but it does not have any effect.

You can try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/HJ8xYLPq4

Comment: how did you add the hidden character?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not identical. The first character is different (although it looks identical to the naked eye)

Try

```
 print([ord(c) for c in a])
 print([ord(c) for c in b])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can ignore small differences like this one, try:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

word_1 = "comentar"

word_2 = " comentar"

result = SequenceMatcher(a=word_1, b=word_2).ratio() > 0.9

print(result)
```

This will return True